# Unable to find "artifactory" in the list of "service connections" in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, artifactory, serviceconnection

I am new to Azure Devops and integration of Azure Devops with Artifactory.
I am following up the documentation and trying to add a service connection to Artifactory, from my free account of Azure Devops.

But I cannot find "Artifactory" in the list of service connections, as mentioned in the documentation.
Can somebody please help me how to create a service connection to Artifactory?

Documentation link : https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Azure+DevOps+Extension#ArtifactoryAzureDevOpsExtension-ConfiguringtheArtifactoryServiceEndpoint

Below is the list of service connections which I see in my Azure Devops :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Azure Devops, you need to install the extension: [JFrog Artifactory](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JFrog.jfrog-artifactory-vsts-extension).

Then you could get the `Artifactory Service Connections`

[image]

Here is a doc about [installing the Extension in Azure Devops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/marketplace/install-extension?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) (Search `JFrog Artifactory`).

Answer (score 4):

In order to work with Artifactory from the Azure Devops, you need to install the Artifactory plugin. Please refer to this [JFrog wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Azure+DevOps+Extension) for more insights.